# R match part of string against vector of strings

Tags: r, string, match

I have a comma separated character class

```
A = "123,456,789"
```

and I am trying to get a logical vector for when one of the items in the character class are present in a character array.

```
B <- as.array(c("456", "135", "789", "111"))
```

I am looking for logical result of size 4 (length of B)

```
[1] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Fairly new to R so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of sapply and grepl, which returns a logical if matched

```
 sapply(B, grepl, x=A)
```

Comment: I'd go with the non-looping method in the other answer

Answer (score 4):

Since your comparison vector is comma-separated, you can use this as a non-looping method.

```
B %in% strsplit(A, ",")[[1]]
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

And one other looping method would be to use `Vectorize` with `grepl`.  This uses `mapply` internally.

```
Vectorize(grepl, USE.NAMES = FALSE)(B, A)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```